# display variable with table columns (select statement) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

Here I want To display Variables Values with Columns of tables

```
declare @BaseMetal varchar(40)
set @BaseMetal='18K'

 SELECT   CAST(@BaseMetal as varchar(40)) 'BaseMetal', tbl.Columm1,tbl.Columm2, tbl.Columm3 from tbl
```

O/P should be :

```
BaseMetal   Columm1   Columm2     Columm3 
  18K       colval1    colval1    colval1
  18K       colval2    colval2    colval2
```

But when i tried it shows error of `Must declare the scalar variable "@BaseMetal".`

Comment: Did you run above code? It works for me.

Comment: Yes it is Write It was My Mistake. I Just run only select statement...sorry

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the cast.

```
declare @BaseMetal varchar(40)
set @BaseMetal='18K'

SELECT   @BaseMetal AS 'BaseMetal', tbl.Columm1,tbl.Columm2, tbl.Columm3 from tbl
```